# How to draw text in a canvas vertical + horizontal with Delphi 10.2

Tags: delphi, fonts, draw

I want to draw on a canvas a word vertically and next to it a word horizontally.
I used a old suggestion like this :

in the maiForm's create event :

```
GetObject(MainForm.Font.Handle,SizeOf(TLogFont),@LogFont);
NewLogFont := LogFont;
NewLogFont.lfEscapement := 900;
NewFont := CreateFontIndirect(NewLogFont);
OldFont := MainForm.Font.Handle;
```

where

```
LogFont,NewLogFont  : TLogFont;
NewFont,OldFont     : HFont;
```

and in drawing routine :

```
fontTemp := TFont.Create;
fontTemp.Assign(aCanvas.Font);
......
aCanvas.Font.Handle := newFont; // if i coment this line the two strings drawn verically else both drawn horizonatlly
aCanvas.Font.Size := 8;
h := textHeight('1');
aCanvas.textOut(x,y,aString);
aCanvas.Font.Assign(fontTemp);
aCanvas.textOut(x+20,y,bString);
.....
fontTemp.Free;
```

In my old application (D2007) it worked ok but in Delphi 10.2, the change of orientation (from vert to horiz) changes both strings to horiz. 
Any help please ?

Comment: Try simply resetting `aCanvas.Font.Handle` instead of using `Assign()`, eg: `OldFont := aCanvas.Font.Handle; aCanvas.Font.Handle := newFont; try ... finally aCanvas.Font.Handle := OldFont; end;`

Comment: I try your suggestion but nothing changed.

Answer (score 8):

No, as you said it is not an *absolutely rare* code. This approach lets you rotate text *without* using `VCL`'s canvas properties.

### Pure WinAPI for output text with rotation

The code below uses no `VCL`'s capabilities to output rotated text onto provided device context (`HDC`).

```
procedure TForm1.DrawTextRotatedA(ADC: HDC; AFontHandle: HFONT; 
  Angle, X, Y: Integer; AColor: COLORREF; AText: String);
var
  LogFont: tagLOGFONT;
  OldFontHandle: HFONT;
  NewFontHandle: HFONT;
begin
  if (ADC = 0) or (AFontHandle = 0) then
    Exit;

  if GetObject(AFontHandle, SizeOf(LogFont), @LogFont) = 0 then
    Exit;

  // Set color of text and its rotation angle
  SetTextColor(ADC, AColor);
  if Angle > 360 then
    Angle := 0;
  LogFont.lfEscapement := Angle * 10;
  LogFont.lfCharset := 1;
  LogFont.lfOutPrecision := OUT_TT_PRECIS;
  LogFont.lfQuality := PROOF_QUALITY;

  // Create new font
  NewFontHandle := CreateFontIndirect(LogFont);
  try
    OldFontHandle := SelectObject(ADC, NewFontHandle);
    try
      // Output result
      SetBKMode(ADC, TRANSPARENT);
      try
        TextOut(ADC, X, Y, LPCWSTR(AText), Length(AText));
      finally
        SetBKMode(ADC, OPAQUE);
      end;
    finally
      // Restore font handle
      NewFontHandle := SelectObject(ADC, OldFontHandle);
    end;
  finally
    // Delete font handle
    DeleteObject(NewFontHandle);
  end;
end;
```

There are places for improvements but this is just an example to prove you are wrong calling such a code *rare*. This example expects `HFONT` as one of arguments to perform all actions over it. You probably could get font handle from `TControl` by using `WM_GETFONT` message, but most of `VCL`'s components don't honor this message (it works, f.e. with `TListView` which returns correct font handle). Trying to get font handle from `HDC` returns `System` font that doesn't support rotation at all. Perhaps I did something wrong but I have acted accordingly to `microsoft.docs`.

### Using VCL for output text with rotation

I didn't get what code you have provide in your question should to do (it is cannot be compiled) so I rewrite it to show you how to output rotated text *with using VCL's capabilities*.

```
procedure TForm1.DrawTextRotatedB(ACanvas: TCanvas; Angle, X, Y: Integer; 
  ATextColor: TColor; AText: String);
var
  NewX: Integer;
  NewY: integer;
  Escapement: Integer;
  LogFont: TLogFont;
  NewFontHandle: HFONT;
  OldFontHandle: HFONT;
begin
  if not Assigned(ACanvas) then
    Exit;

  // Get handle of font and prepare escapement
  GetObject(ACanvas.Font.Handle, SizeOf(LogFont), @LogFont);
  if Angle > 360 then
    Angle := 0;
  Escapement := Angle * 10;

  // We must initialise all fields of the record structure
  LogFont.lfWidth := 0;
  LogFont.lfHeight := ACanvas.Font.Height;
  LogFont.lfEscapement := Escapement;
  LogFont.lfOrientation := 0;
  if fsBold in ACanvas.Font.Style then
    LogFont.lfWeight := FW_BOLD
  else
    LogFont.lfWeight := FW_NORMAL;
  LogFont.lfItalic := Byte(fsItalic in ACanvas.Font.Style);
  LogFont.lfUnderline := Byte(fsUnderline in ACanvas.Font.Style);
  LogFont.lfStrikeOut := Byte(fsStrikeOut in ACanvas.Font.Style);
  LogFont.lfCharSet := ACanvas.Font.Charset;
  LogFont.lfOutPrecision := OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
  LogFont.lfClipPrecision := CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
  LogFont.lfQuality := DEFAULT_QUALITY;
  LogFont.lfPitchAndFamily := DEFAULT_PITCH;
  StrPCopy(LogFont.lfFaceName, ACanvas.Font.Name);

  // Create new font with rotation
  NewFontHandle := CreateFontIndirect(LogFont);
  try
    // Set color of text
    ACanvas.Font.Color := ATextColor;

    // Select the new font into the canvas
    OldFontHandle := SelectObject(ACanvas.Handle, NewFontHandle);
    try
      // Output result
      ACanvas.Brush.Style := VCL.Graphics.bsClear;
      try
        ACanvas.TextOut(X, Y, AText);
      finally
        ACanvas.Brush.Style := VCL.Graphics.bsSolid;
      end;
    finally
      // Restore font handle
      NewFontHandle := SelectObject(ACanvas.Handle, OldFontHandle);
    end;
  finally
    // Delete the deselected font object
    DeleteObject(NewFontHandle);
  end;
end;
```

### Using case

Here is the code showing how to use procedures for rotating text.

```
procedure TForm1.aButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DC: HDC;
begin
  Repaint;

  DC := GetDC(Handle);
  try
    DrawTextRotatedA(DC, Canvas.Font.Handle, TrackBar1.Position, 100, 100, clNavy, 'String');
  finally
    ReleaseDC(Handle, DC);
  end;

  DrawTextRotatedB(Canvas, TrackBar1.Position, 200, 100, clNavy, 'String');
end;
```

Sometimes it is faster to output rotated text onto DC without VCL. This could be useful if you are trying to deal with control that have no access to canvas. F.e. if you will try to paint `tooltip` (`tooltip_class32`) in your own style you probably might want to use the first method to output text (rotated or not).

### Information

Here are links from `docs.microsoft`. they describe how and why one or another function was used.

- [About Device Contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/device-contexts)
- [TextOutW function](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-textoutw)
- [SetTextColor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-settextcolor)
- [tagLOGFONTW structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-taglogfontw)
- [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject)
- [WM_GETFONT message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/wm-getfont)

Comment: Thanks, your answer is usefull for other situations but, for me, is absolutely easy to use eg  canvas.font.orientation := 900; textOut(....); canvas.font.orientation := 0; textOut(....); etc

Comment: @JimPapas I agree with you. Setting `Font.Orientation` is a really fast way to rotate text, but I made this answer to prove you that you are wrong when you have said (citation): *All this stuf I used is absolutely rare*. It is *not rare*; it is still *can be used* with success for any cases along with `Font.Orientation` property.

Answer (score -2):

It's simple!
TFont has the property orientation that does the work! All this stuf I used is absolutely rare.

Comment: Please reconsider your understanding of "rare".