# GDIPLUS in Delphi - string from TTnTEdit

Tags: delphi, gdi+

I am trying to draw a rotated text in Arab to a paintbox, using Delphi 6. Tried different tools like GR32 and now GDIPLUS.

GDIPLUS Samples work fine, I can draw the "Hello":

```
  graphics := TGPGraphics.Create(PaintBox.Canvas.Handle);
  fontFamily:= TGPFontFamily.Create('Times New Roman');
  font := TGPFont.Create(fontFamily, 24, FontStyleRegular, UnitPixel);
  pointF := MakePoint(30.0, 10.0);
  solidBrush:= TGPSolidBrush.Create(MakeColor(255, 0, 0, 255));
  r :=  graphics.DrawString('Hello', -1, font, pointF, solidBrush);
  showmessage( GetEnumName(
        typeinfo(Tstatus), ord(r)  )
     );
  fontFamily.Free;
  font.Free;
  solidBrush.Free;
  graphics.Free;
```

When run, I get my "Hello" drawn in the Paintbox as expected, and an "OK" status back.

Now I change the string in DrawString (which IS a widestring parameter) to accept input from a TTnTEdit I placed on canvas.

```
  thestring := TNTEdt1.Text;   
  r :=  graphics.DrawString(thestring , -1, font, pointF, solidBrush);
```

Now I get NOTHING printed, and still OK returned.

**I would expect a TTnTEdit to actually return a widestring ?**

EDIT: I should point out that it does not matter what content the TNTEdit has, even if I put "Hello".

Comment: I guess Graphics.DrawString is the ascii/ansi variant, not the unicode variant. If you pass a WideString, if the first BYTE (not character) is 0, it is considered as end of string and nothing displayed.

Comment: You should update your application with latest Delphi wich support Unicode and will out of the box use almost any language with any component. You don't need TTnEdit at all, just use a standard TEdit. And TCanvas will also use Unicode. There is a free Community Edition you can even use for small business.

Comment: Strangely I can pass a variable to DrawString, defined in the function as Widestring, and it works fine. I can't directly upgrade Delphi as I have a large codebase to maintain which can't directly upgrade.

Comment: Not a good idea to get glued to Delphi 6 on the long term. I urge you to migrate. Well written D6 programs can be migrated easily. The only real issue is with old 3rd party component for which you don't have the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use *Tnt Delphi Unicode Controls* already you could also use **TntGraphics.pas** for `Widestring` output on a `TCanvas`, simply by issuing:

```
TntGraphics.WideCanvasTextOut( MyPaintBox.Canvas, x, y, MyTntEdit.Text );
```

Since your question mentioned rotating the text but your code nowhere tries so have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923681/4299358)'s method `DrawTextRotatedB()` and use that one. Of course: change `String` to `Widestring` and `ACanvas.TextOut(X, Y, AText)` into my example code line. Successfully tried this using D7 and I'm pretty sure it will also work with D6:

[image: rotated text: Arabian, Katakana, Kanji]

Comment: Thank you @AmigoJack. The rotate part is simple, it's adding one line for GDI+ graphics object. What's strange is that GDI+ dll calls specifically refers to Widestring all the way. See https://pasteboard.co/JxjzCXZ.jpg

Comment: Try providing the actual length instead of `-1`. Does `graphics.DrawString( Widestring('Hello'), -1, ... )` also fail?