# How can I put emojis in a TButton or TBitBtn Caption

Tags: delphi

I'm working with Delphi 10.4.2, creating a VCL app on Windows 10, and I'd like to display some face emojis on buttons in place of normal text. I'm wondering if it can be done using Unicode characters rather than glyphs?

If I have a component with a `Caption` property, I know it's a `String` type. And since Delphi 2009 that means they're Unicode.

What's not clear to me is when Emoji's are treated as glyphs (little graphic images) vs Unicode characters. If they're characters, that means there needs to be a character set they're contained in, right? But when I look at similar questions for different platforms, it seems it varies by app, as they all have their own emoji sets. And the only examples I'm finding are for virtual keyboards that insert them into a memo or something on a mobile device.

What I'm doing is using some buttons to display one to five '*'s for indicating a general ranking.

I thought it would be fun to replace the '*'s with different emojis. Something like:

```
1 = 1x<frown>, 
2 = 2x<unsure>, 
3 = 3x<raised-eye>, 
4 = 4x<smile>, and 
5 = 5x<laugh>.
```

I'm not sure how to capture the emojis as strings to let me paste them into the code as string literals, and I'm not sure it would even work. Google is not being very helpful at returning relevant hits.

Comment: "Emojis" are Unicode characters just like English letters, ∫, ∑, ⌬, ξ, and ᚥ. Here's an example: . Just ordinary text. You only need to copy and paste. And of course the target OS needs to support such text, and there must be a font with a glyph for the "emoji" you need.

Comment: (I'm using Windows 7 and Delphi 10.3, and I am not able to get at least this "emoji" to render properly. It might work on Windows 10.)

Comment: I just added that info at the top.

Comment: I mean, A is U+0041: LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A, ∫ is U+222B: INTEGRAL, and  is U+1F913: NERD FACE.

Comment: Where do you find the emoji character map?

Comment: You may use https://home.unicode.org/. There are many other sites, though.

Comment: I found this. It looks very helpful. Just sharing it for anybody reading this.
https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Comment: Under Windows 7 I've installed [Unifont 13.0.06](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/unifont/unifont-13.0.06/) and [NotoColorEmoji](https://github.com/googlefonts/noto-emoji/blob/main/fonts/NotoColorEmoji_WindowsCompatible.ttf) which both support U+1F913 and failed to render that character in _Notepad_ (correctly encoded UTF-16 as `0x3e d8 13 dd`) and _Delphi 7_ (also using surrogates). I guess the system just can't cope with Unicode 8.0...

Comment: You can't use Unicode strings in the VCL in Delphi 7, since the `string` type is `AnsiString` in that version. You have to use 3rd party Unicode UI controls instead, such as from TntWare.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I used to `CreateWindowExW( ...'BUTTON'... )` even before _Tnt Unicode Controls_ was a thing - [I work with Unicode in D7 24/7 without problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64525456/4299358) and that wasn't my point. My point is Unicode 8.0 under Windows 7 in general: the font renderer simply may not be capable.

Comment: @AmigoJack sure, you could use Unicode APIs manually (that is what Tnt did), that will bypass the VCL's native processing. "*My point is Unicode 8.0 under Windows 7 in general: the font renderer simply may not be capable*" - you didn't make that point clear earlier.

Comment: When I copy a colorful emoji from a web page and paste it into a string in the Delphi IDE, it's a much simpler drawing that just has two colors. More like a simple pen-and-paper look. It appears the same on the button at run-time, and both look very different than the emoji I selected. aBtn.Caption := '☹'; vs. something much more colorful and rich like   copied from above.

Comment: @David: That might be because the relevant OS APIs don't support this. The system (Windows) correctly renders the character, but doesn't realise "hey, this is one of these 'emoji' characters that are typically rendered as coloured glyphs, so let's do that instead of rendering it like a 'normal' character". I am pretty sure the Windows 10 OS supports coloured 'emojis', but maybe not in desktop applications using the classic Win32 API. For instance, press Win+R and then Win+. (period) and pick some colourful 'emoji'. Then try the same thing in Notepad. You see: old-style rendering.

Comment: (cont.) Now try the same thing in Edge's address bar. You get the colourful thing.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thanks, but how can that be addressed in a Delphi app?

Comment: @David By drawing those characters all the way yourself, just like Edge does. Good luck.