# Why do TPanel.Canvas.Font properties (accessed with protected hack) differ from TPanel.Font properties?

Tags: delphi, canvas, vcl, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm using the `DrawTextRotatedB` function from [Josef Švejk's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52923681/512728) to the question [How to draw text in a canvas vertical + horizontal with Delphi 10.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916612/how-to-draw-text-in-a-canvas-vertical-horizontal-with-delphi-10-2)
to draw text vertically on a `TPanel`.
That component does not have a public Canvas property, so I'm using the protected hack to access it:

```
type
   THackPanel = class(TPanel);

DrawTextRotated(THackPanel(PnlLeftLeft).Canvas,90, PnlLeftLeft.Width DIV 2, cVertDrawOffset, FLeftVertText)

with definition

procedure DrawTextRotated(ACanvas: TCanvas; Angle, X, Y: Integer; AText: String);
```

The procedure uses `ACanvas.Font` properties to draw text using `ACanvas.TextOut`.
I noticed that inside the procedure these properties were not what I had expected, e.g.

```
PnlLeftLeft.Font.Size = 20
PnlLeftLeft.Font.Ttyle = [fsBold]

THackPanel(PnlLeftLeft).Canvas.Font.Size = 10
THackPanel(PnlLeftLeft).Canvas.Font.Ttyle = []
```

It seems that I can easily 'fix' this doing `THackPanel(PnlLeftLeft).Canvas.Font := PnlLeftLeft.Font;` right before the procedure call,
but I'm still left with the question:

Why don't `TPanel.Canvas.Font` properties the mirror the `TPanel.Font` properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design.

A complex control may write text with different fonts at different times and locations, and so `Canvas.Font` – which dictates the font of the next text-drawing operation – may vary even during the painting of a single "frame".

`Self.Font`, on the other hand, is the "primary font" of the control, which is often displayed in the Object Inspector (being a published property) and affected by the `ParentFont` property.

For example, a control's painting code might assign `Self.Font` to `Canvas.Font` at the beginning of each invocation and then possibly alter it slightly during painting (maybe to draw some parts in italics or boldface or some different colour).